# Can Toad (for Oracle) connect to a database I've created in my computer?

Tags: oracle, ms-access, toad

I've created a database via MS Access & I've created some tables within it. I want to know if it's possible to access it via Toad & how can I achieve it.

I managed to create the DB, but I'm seeing that Toad has three options for connection: TNS Names, LDAP or Direct (I don't really know the difference between the three). What would I need to do to connect it successfully?

I'm expecting to be able to login to my Database using Toad & do queries on it.

Comment: TOAD for Oracle can only connect to Oracle databases.  Not to Access databases.  If you created a local Access database, you'd need to use a different tool to connect.  If you want to use TOAD, you'd want to create a local Oracle database.

Comment: @JustinCave Are you sure on that? [This thread on Toad's forums](https://forums.toadworld.com/t/toad-13-1-error-could-not-load-the-microsoft-access-database-engine/44617) appears to suggest that you can with the correct drivers.

Comment: @MT0 - That thread is talking about exporting data to Access, not connecting to an Access database.  Oracle's SQL Developer can connect to any JDBC data source so you could use that to connect to Access (though 99 of people would just use Access to interact with the database).  I've not encountered a version of TOAD that would do that.